# Remove image in pdf document with itextsharp

Tags: itext

I have a requirement to add image to pdf documents and being able later to remove the image if needed.

I manage to add image to documents with this code :

```
iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle pagesize;

PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(sourceFile), new PdfWriter(destinationPath));
int n = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages();

ImageData img = ImageDataFactory.Create(image_WM_Path);

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    pagesize = pdfDoc.GetPage(i).GetPageSizeWithRotation();

    float f = pagesize.GetWidth() / (1.5f * img.GetWidth());
    float wImage = img.GetWidth() * f;
    float hImage = img.GetHeight() * f;

    iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle rectangle = new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(pagesize.GetRight() - wImage, pagesize.GetBottom(),wImage, hImage );

    PdfStampAnnotation stamp = new PdfStampAnnotation(rectangle);
    stamp.SetStampName(new PdfName("MyCustomStamp"));

    PdfFormXObject xObj = new PdfFormXObject(new iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle(wImage, hImage));
    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xObj, pdfDoc);
    canvas.AddImage(img, 0, 0, wImage, false);
    stamp.SetNormalAppearance(xObj.GetPdfObject());

    pdfDoc.GetPage(i).AddAnnotation(stamp);
}

pdfDoc.Close();
```

Is it the correct way to add image as annotation ?
Do i really put an id with the SetStampName method ?

I don't manage to retrieve the annotation in the page's PdfDictionary annotation array, the array is null :

```
PdfArray annotations = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.Annotation);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: *"My first question, is it the right way of adding image ?"* - This depends on the requirements. Your code adds the image to the content stream. If the requirement is easy removal, adding it as an annotation might be more appropriate.*"Second question, when adding images this way is it possible to later identify them in the document and remove them ?"* - Your code does nothing special, so you can hardly differentiate between images your code added and images similar code by others add. *"Giving the image a specific id"* is a good idea.

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. If i understand correctly i could give an id to the image through an annotation ? Or is it two things completely different ?

Comment: **A** You can give an ID to an image by adding a custom tag to the image dictionary. But that only makes the image easier to identify and still not easy to remove from the content stream. **B** You can add the image to an annotation instead of the content stream. The annotation is easy to remove but per se not yet easy to identify. **C** You can combine the approaches by adding the image to an annotation and giving an ID to that annotation to make this easy to identify and to remove.

Comment: Ok thank you. i 'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I edited my original post following your advice.

Comment: I am able to delete on the first page the anotation i added with pdfDoc.GetFirstPage().GetPdfObject().Remove(PdfName.Annots); But i cant target a specific annotation

Comment: If you created the annotation with a specific ID, you could recognize it and remove it specifically.